# Android - Force object to match parent while parent is wrap content

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I'm trying to create some layout for recyclerview. I have a view. I wnat that view to be as long as its parent. But since I will use that layout in recycler view, Parent must be wrap content. And if I make that view match parent parent also become match parent. How can I solve this?

[Example İmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pGoT.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) for that, make one view `wrap content` / `match_parent` and just constraint another view to it vertically + make sure this view have `android:layout_height="0dp"` so he will have the same height as the second view, **something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Wrap content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="same height"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button" />
```

And now whenever your left button will change in height so does the right button.

**Here is how it looks (with the added constrains) for better understanding:**

[image]